# Best way to get a Java Object from a JSON string using com.jackson.?

Tags: java, jackson

Specifically, I am dealing with a JSON string representing an Array containing numbers and other arrays of numbers - these strings are of the form `String string = "[0, [1, 2], [3, 4]]"`.  It represents data of the form `[ channelID, [price, amount],  [price, amount]  ... [price, amount]]`;  The repeating data can be varying lengths.

My end goal is to turn this string into an object of the form `ChannelObject { channel: 0, data: [PriceObject { price: 1, amount: 2 }, PriceObject { price: 3, amount: 4 }] }`.

Jackson's native objectMapper throws errors while trying to read the value of an un-encapsulated JSON array to a class, and the only solution I have found is by giving the ObjectMapper parser the string `{ "data": %s }`, substituting in the original JSON, and using class with property `@JsonProperty ArrayNode data`, but I'm afraid this is an inefficient approach as far as performance.

Is writing a deserializer for "naked" JSON arrays the smartest approach? Is there an easier solution I am missing?

Responses are much appreciated.

**Additional info:**

ObjectMapper doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "[17847,[5391.9,0,-1]";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<ChannelData> list = mapper.readValue(input, ChannelData[].class);
}

public class ChannelData {
    private int channel;

    private List<Data> data;

    public ChannelData(int channel, List<Data> data) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class Data {
    private BigDecimal price;

    private int count;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    public Data() {
    }

    public Data(BigDecimal price, int count, BigDecimal amount) {
        this.price = price;
        this.count = count;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `co.myproject.Application$ChannelData` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (17847)
 at [Source: (String)"[17847,[5391.9,0,-1]]"; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromInt(ValueInstantiator.java:262)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromInt(StdValueInstantiator.java:356)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromNumber(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1324)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:173)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:195)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at co.myproject.Application.run(Application.java:27)
    at co.myproject.Application.main(Application.java:39)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What did you try? There is nothing particularly difficult about that JSON to parse.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas 
I edited with an error and some code. I agree that it should be a pretty painless operation. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly specifies there is no default constructor (which is no argument constructor) in your `ChannelData` class, create no argument constructor in `ChannelData` class.

Since you declared `public ChannelData(int channel, List<Data> data)` `ChannelData` argument constructor, it is your responsibility to declare no argument constructor

```
public class ChannelData {
      public ChannelData() { // no arg constructor }
```